# Why are transform values in inspector different from animation tab?

Tags: unity

I’m trying to make animation in timeline. But transform values in animation tab and inspector are different from each other. It causes problem when ı try to rotate player. It doesn’t rotate the way I want.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Let me say first that Unity inaccuracies on the scale of, i.e. 0.00001 is completely normal.

In your case, it's far off from that. The reason to that could have different reasons.

If it rotates back to it's original position for example it might be because of "Apply Root Motion" being unchecked.

However, in your case, it seems to be a general problem.
The warning message at the bottom could be the reason why this problem occurs. Setting an inital offset on rotation can mess up transform values. So make sure that your rotation is set to 0, 0, 0 prior to recording.

If there are more Unity warning messages, please share them so we can help out further.

Comment: Really thanks for your interest . I found solution

1)Right click "Rotation" on the left side of the animation pane

2)Hover "Interpolation"

3) Select Quaternion

And ıt worked! Now the object rotates the way I rotate